# Webpack and Vue 2.0 UglifyJsPlugin scss calc transform issue

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, calc, html-webpack-plugin

Currently, I've written a webpack task to compile vue files.

In production mode, I use UglifyJsPlugin to minify and compress the index.js, it works pretty fine for a long time.

However I found that in production mode the style in scss

```
width: calc(100% / 3);
```

is transformed to

```
width: 33.33333%;
```

which will cause a black line on my pages.

I tried remove postcss and it doesn't work. Finally I found that if I remove UglifyJsPlugin it works very fine, but the file is too large, I have to minify it by using online compress service.

Here is the part of webpack task

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const htmlFiles = glob.sync('./dev/*.html');
    const htmlPlugins = htmlFiles.map((file, i) =>
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: path.basename(file),
            template: file,
            inject: false,
            minify:{
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
            },
    }));

webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
    plugins: [
        ...htmlPlugins,
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                drop_console: true,
            },
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: './dev',
            },
        ], {
            ignore: [
                '*.html',
                'router.js',
                'style/**/*',
                'script/**/*',
                'store/**/*',
                'vendor/**/*',
                'component/**/*',
                'data/**/*',
                'font/**/*',
            ]}),
       ]});
    }
```

and the postcss.config.js is

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-cssnext')({
            features: {
                calc: false,
            },
        }),
        require('postcss-sorting')(),
    ],
};
```

is there is some way to prevent uglyfyJs from changing calc?

Answer (score 0):

In scss loader, I added -minimize

```
scss: 'style!css?-minimize!postcss!sass',
```

and it works really fine.

More, I found that in webpack2, the uglyfyJs works really good. Don't think many people will occur to it in the future.